# want to rid from bubbling event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a confirmation section with jquery. I have a cancel button that displayed the confirmation message. Then again click on that confirmation buttons that is YES and NO.

here is the jsfiddle of my script: http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/TVfM9/

first click on cancel then you get yes and no button, pressing no shows you first stat that is cancel button, then again click on cancel and after that press yes, yes show you the alert message but with bubble alert box as many time we try it without refresh, hope you understand,

Can anyone tell me where i missed something?

```
$('input[name="cancel_upload"]').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var that    = $(this), 
                s_t     = $('.status'),                    
                c_b     = $('#cncl'),                
                c_c     = $('#cncl-conf'),                
                c_y     = $('input[name="cancel_y"]'),      
                c_n     = $('input[name="cancel_n"]');      

            c_b.hide();
            c_c.show();
            s_t.html('Cancel Transfer')
               .next()
               .hide();

            //Trigger Handle
            var combo = c_y.add(c_n);
            combo.click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                if(e.target.name == 'cancel_n')
                {
                    c_b.show();
                    c_c.hide();
                    s_t.html('Transferring...')
                       .next()
                       .show();
                } 
                else
                {
                    alert('Going to Cancel');
                    c_b.show();
                    c_c.hide();
                    s_t.html('Transferring...')
                       .next()
                       .show();
                }

            });

            return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem does not have anything to do with event bubbling, it is because you have duplicate event handlers registered in each click of the cancel button

You should not register an event handler inside another event handler without removing teh previous handlers.

In this case I would suggest adding the event handlers outside the click handler

Try

```
var  s_t     = $('.status'),                    
    c_b     = $('#cncl'),                
    c_c     = $('#cncl-conf'),
    c_y     = $('input[name="cancel_y"]'),      
    c_n     = $('input[name="cancel_n"]');


//Trigger Handle
var combo = c_y.add(c_n);
combo.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if(e.target.name == 'cancel_n')
    {
        c_b.show();
        c_c.hide();
        s_t.html('Transferring...')
        .next()
        .show();
    } 
    else
    {
        alert('Going to Cancel');
        c_b.show();
        c_c.hide();
        s_t.html('Transferring...')
        .next()
        .show();
    }

});

$('input[name="cancel_upload"]').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var that    = $(this);      

    c_b.hide();
    c_c.show();
    s_t.html('Cancel Transfer')
    .next()
    .hide();

    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HuhLF/)

Comment: humm, i was thinking this. but i though might be i found some solution.